# SQLAlchemy - Ordered relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a relationship between between two tables, Accounts and 
Items:

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    account_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_order = Column(ARRAY(Integer))

    items = relationship(?)

class Item(Base):
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.account_id'))
```

When I get all items for an account, they need to be in order. The order is stored in "item_order" on accounts, otherwise assumed to be ordered by item_id.

Here's is how I'd query all of the items for an account:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts A INNER JOIN items T USING (account_id)
WHERE A.account_id=1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN A.item_order IS NOT NULL THEN nullif(idx(A.item_order, T.item_id::int), 0)
ELSE
    T.item_id
END
NULLS LAST;
```

Is it possible to get this into an SQLAlchemy relationship?

Comment: If you can change the model, I suggest you read the [OrderingList](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) extension documentation, remove `item_order` from `Account` and add `item_order = Column(Integer)` to the `Item`.

Comment: I don't want to update all the items when their order changes, which is why I've stored the order in an array on the account.